# Nothing appears when I plot using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am new to plotting in python. I want to make a county choropleth. I'm attempting the code below. I get no errors but I also get no plot. I assumed a separate window would appear with my visual in it. Spyder just ran the code and nothing. I'm new to python so maybe my expectations are wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

fips = ['06021', '06023', '06027',
        '06029', '06033', '06059',
        '06047', '06049', '06051',
        '06055', '06061']
values = range(len(fips))

fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values)
fig.layout.template = None
fig.show()
```

When I run this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

a plot is produced.

Found a solution. The problem is the code below plots the results in a new browser window as a html type thing. I plan on incorporating this output into a Microsoft PowerBI dashboard. Thus, I think I need the output to appear in the Ipython console. I'm using spyder.

```
fips    values
01234   2348564 
12356   897
10012   984375
```

```
fips = y_2017['NewFIPS'].tolist()
values = y_2017['Yr_Neg_Money_Cnty'].tolist()

colorscale=["#f7fbff","#ebf3fb","#deebf7","#d2e3f3","#c6dbef",
            "#b3d2e9","#9ecae1", "#85bcdb","#6baed6",
            "#57a0ce","#4292c6","#3082be","#2171b5",
            "#1361a9","#08519c","#0b4083","#08306b"]

endpts = list(np.linspace(1, 3000000, len(colorscale) - 1))

fig = ff.create_choropleth(fips=fips, values=values, colorscale= colorscale, binning_endpoints=endpts)
py.offline.plot(fig)
```

fig.show() might be what I'm looking for but still cannot get it to work.

Comment: which plot are you trying to plot? a line graph or choropleth?

Comment: Make sure you have plotly-geo installed if you are trying to create a choroploth.

Comment: I'm trying to make a choropleth.

Comment: have you looked at the offline ploting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764157/plotly-choropleth-not-plotting-data)?

Comment: Possibly there is an issue with setting the GDAL environment. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883445/how-to-fix-the-enviroment-variable-gdal-data-path-set/55465669#55465669