# Plotly Choropleth Map not Displaying Correctly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

First off, I'd like to start by saying that I am asking this question since I do not believe that it is related to the similarly titled question: [plotly choropleth not plotting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764157/plotly-choropleth-not-plotting-data), as I believe it has something to do with the custom GEOJSON boundaries and/or how I am accessing the data.

I use the `crime.csv` table from https://www.kaggle.com/ankkur13/boston-crime-data, and I am using a GEOJSON file from Boston Analytics (Fetched in the script). Currently, my code runs without errors, but it does not load the data onto the plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

# Read Dataset
# Located at: https://www.kaggle.com/ankkur13/boston-crime-data
df = pd.read_csv("crime.csv")

with urlopen('http://bostonopendata-boston.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/9a3a8c427add450eaf45a470245680fc_5.geojson?outSR={%22latestWkid%22:2249,%22wkid%22:102686}') as response:
    pd_districts = json.load(response)

df_agg = df.groupby("DISTRICT").agg(CRIMES=("YEAR","count")) 
df_agg.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_agg = df_agg[df_agg['DISTRICT'] != 'nan']

df['DISTRICT'] = df['DISTRICT'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=pd_districts, 
    locations=df_agg['DISTRICT'].unique(), 
    z=df_agg['CRIMES'], 
    featureidkey="features.properties.DISTRICT")
)

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron")
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
fig.show()
```

I believe it has something to do with my `featureidkey`. However, I have tried multiple variants such as `properties.DISTRICT`, `properties.ID`, but to no avail.

I also ran a few sanity checks to make sure that the data was accessible, and here they are:

```
print(df_agg['DISTRICT'].unique())
print(pd_districts['features'][0]['properties']['ID'])
print(df['DISTRICT'].dtype)
```

Any help would be appreciated.